# How does one unset the hard outlines in mac finder windows?

Tags: finder, windows, settings, setup

I just got a new mac and it seems things are really bright. I selected the high contrast or high outlines...can't remember what the name was. See how it's really white especially on the outside:

[image]

how do I undo that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System Preference > Accessibility`. Choose `Display` then untick `Increase Contrast`.